# ORACLE - run query available in a table column and use result for insert into another column

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, insert, cursor

I have a table with sql queries:

TABLE_A

```
ID DESCRITION SQL
1  Test1      select count(*) from test1 group by..
2  Test2      select count(*) from test2 group by..
3  Test3      select count(*) from test3 group by..
```

I would like to execute the selects from TABLE_A.SQL column and use the results in inserts statements that will populate another table.
Meaning:

```
insert into TABLE_B (TABLE_A.Description for ID=1, TABLE_A.SQL_RESULT for ID=1)
insert into TABLE_B (TABLE_A.Description for ID=2, TABLE_A.SQL_RESULT for ID=2)
insert into TABLE_B (TABLE_A.Description for ID=3, TABLE_A.SQL_RESULT for ID=3)
```

In not clear for me how I can do this using PLSQL block.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need dynamic SQL for that.

Tables:

```
SQL> create table table_a (id, c_descr, c_sql) as
  2    (select 1, 'EMP' , 'select count(*) from emp'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'DEPT', 'select count(*) from dept' from dual);

Table created.

SQL> create table table_b (c_descr varchar2(20), result number);

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str table_a.c_sql%type;
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select c_descr, c_sql from table_a) loop
  6      execute immediate cur_r.c_sql into l_cnt;
  7      insert into table_b (c_descr, result) values (cur_r.c_descr, l_cnt);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_b;

C_DESCR                  RESULT
-------------------- ----------
EMP                          14
DEPT                          4

SQL>
```

---

If `select` statements really contain `group by` clauses, then result isn't just a single value, but set of them. For example:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp group by deptno;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5
         6
         3

SQL>
```

In that case, it is still dynamic SQL, but this time target of the `into` clause isn't scalar variable but collection:

```
SQL> create table table_a (id, c_descr, c_sql) as
  2    select 3, 'EMP', 'select count(*) from emp group by deptno' from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table table_b (c_descr varchar2(20), result number);

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str table_a.c_sql%type;
  3    l_coll sys.odcinumberlist;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select c_descr, c_sql from table_a) loop
  6      execute immediate cur_r.c_sql bulk collect into l_coll;
  7      insert into table_b (c_descr, result)
  8        select cur_r.c_descr, column_value
  9          from table(l_coll);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_b;

C_DESCR                  RESULT
-------------------- ----------
EMP                           5
EMP                           6
EMP                           3

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, based on your comment]**

Sure, you can "concatenate" result when query returns more than a single row (and you don't want to insert several rows into `table_B`, which is what my previous example does). In that case, one option is to use `listagg` function. Also, `result` column of `table_b` can't be `number` any more.

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

        ID C_D C_SQL
---------- --- ----------------------------------------
         3 EMP select count(*) from emp group by deptno

SQL> alter table table_b modify result varchar2(20);

Table altered.

SQL> declare
  2    l_str table_a.c_sql%type;
  3    l_coll sys.odcinumberlist;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select c_descr, c_sql from table_a) loop
  6      execute immediate cur_r.c_sql bulk collect into l_coll;
  7      insert into table_b (c_descr, result)
  8        select cur_r.c_descr, listagg(column_value, ', ') within group (order by null)
  9          from table(l_coll);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table_b;

C_DESCR              RESULT
-------------------- --------------------
EMP                  5, 6, 3

SQL>
```

---

**[Yet another edit, based on a new comment]**

If you'd want to include additional column(s) into query, the simplest option is to pre-concatenate them in `select` statement. Something like this:

```
SQL> select * from table_a;

        ID C_D C_SQL
---------- --- -------------------------------------------------------
         3 EMP select count(*) ||'-'|| deptno from emp group by deptno
```

`l_coll` is now `sys.odcivarchar2list` (previously, it was `sys.odcinumberlist` as it contained numbers only):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_coll sys.odcivarchar2list;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select c_descr, c_sql from table_a) loop
  5      execute immediate cur_r.c_sql bulk collect into l_coll;
  6      insert into table_b (c_descr, result)
  7        select cur_r.c_descr, listagg(column_value, ', ') within group (order by null)
  8          from table(l_coll);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table_b;

C_DESCR              RESULT
-------------------- ----------------------------------------
EMP                  3-10, 5-20, 6-30

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks. but what if c_sql is like 'select count(*),  deptno from emp group by deptno'? in this case, how we will be able to do the insert if table_b (c_descr, result)? can we do a concatenation between collection elements? is possible to parse only teh result for count(*) ?

Comment: thanks a lot for your replay. but i wanted to ask if in c_sql column select statement has more than one column: 'select count(), deptno from emp group by deptno' in this case how bulk collect will work? in table_b i would like to have in result column something as 13_12A where 13 is result of count() group by deptno and 12A is the corresponding group by deptno and so on for each group

Comment: A simple modification might help; see another edit.

Comment: indeed, but in this way the query in c_sql is modified and is added there a concatenation. That idea is to not concatenate the columns in sql statement available in that column.